# CORS помогите обойти

Tags: angular, cors

Как обойти cors: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
если нет доступа к серверу а запрос выглядит:

```
 axios.post('https://bpm.cosa.ru/ServiceModel/Login', {
      UserName: '1',
      UserPassword: '123',
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'ForceUseSession': true,
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
        // Обработка успешного ответа
        console.log('Успешная авторизация!');
        console.log('Ответ:', response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Обработка ошибки
        console.error('Ошибка авторизации:', error.response.data.message);
      });
```

Попробывал написать proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/*": {
    "target": "https://bpm.cosa.ru",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

добавил его в angular.json

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "web:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "web:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "web:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

запустил проект через ng serve, но cors до сих пор ругаеться